# Lapis Framework does not create new project

Tags: lua, luarocks, openresty

I've already installed Lua, Openresty and Luarocks, but after executing

```
sudo luarocks install lapis
```

or

```
luarocks install lapis --local
```

and then run

```
lapis new
```

in a blank directory and nothing happens

is there a missing step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the problem is that I decided to use the latest versions of Lua and Luarocks, the right way to do it is to use the default version of Lua provided by the Ubuntu 14.04 in my case and the Luarocks provided by apt-get, and not downloading the one from their site. Installing new versions generate incompatibilities.